# How can I determine whether a db entry's collection is part of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

When looping through members of a Db entry, I would like to determine whether or not a particular navigation is part of a many-to-many relationship

When debugging, I can see a property `collection.Metadata.ManyToManyLoader`:

[image]

Which only seems to appear on my many-to-many collections

However, I can't seem to target or select that property in my code:

```
var test = collection.Metadata["ManyToManyLoader"];
var test2 = collection.Metadata.FindAnnotation("ManyToManyLoader");
```

Both `test` and `test2` above are just `null`, even though I can see they shouldn't be in my locals tab

What gives?

Some more code:

```
var entry = DbContext.Entry(entity);

foreach (var collection in entry.Collections)
{
    var test = collection.Metadata["ManyToManyLoader"];
    var test2 = collection.Metadata.FindAnnotation("ManyToManyLoader");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with EF Core 5.0, the `Metadata` property of collection entry is `INavigationBase`. Which could be actually either `INavigation` (for "regular" collection navigations) or `ISkipNavigation` (for skip navigations currently used for implicit many-to-many relationships).

Hence you could check for that interface, e.g.

```cs
if (collection.Metadata is ISkipNavigation info)
{
    // some additional info if needed
    var declaringEntityType = info.DeclaringEntityType; // the entity containing the navigation
    var targetEntityType = info.TargetEntityType; // "other side" entity
    var joinEntityType = info.JoinEntityType; // join entity
    var foreignKey = info.ForeignKey; // foreign key of join entity to this entity
    var inverse = info.Inverse; // the navigation property of the "other side" entity
}
```

etc.

Comment: Amazing, thank you Ivan. Any idea where I can read more about this stuff? When trying to load the many-to-many in question I get this `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'member')` - when they have not been `Include`d, but loading other properties are all OK

Comment: @Bassie Unfortunately they do not document such things, so it's basically looking at interfaces/source code and trial and error.  About "loading many-to-many in question", do you mean `Load` method (е.g. `collection.Load()`)? If you are getting exception, it sounds like bug (and they have a loot). If you wish, you could post separate question with details and repro, along with EFC version in order to see if it needs to go to their issue tracker or we can solve/workaround.

Comment: That sounds about right, Can't seem to find much about this stuff. I added my other question here, but think I found the related bug on github https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835391/why-cant-i-load-many-to-many-entities-into-memory/70836207#70836207

Comment: I saw it. As of EFC 5.0, 6.0, collection navigation property (even private) is *required* at both sides. It's mentioned here [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) at the very beginning *"Many-to-many relationships **require** a collection navigation property on **both** sides"*. So in the above code, `inverse` must be `!= null`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you help me with this tricky LINQ query logic please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840745/problem-in-populating-list-object-in-a-certain-way