# Why can't I load many-to-many entities into memory?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I need to make sure that all related data is loaded into memory after performing some action on an entity

It is done in a generic manner, so for example when loading all collections, we can do:

```
var entry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
foreach (var collection in entry.Collections)
{
    await collection.LoadAsync(cancellationToken);        
}
```

It is working for the most part, but for some reason with my many-to-many relationships which are not yet loaded I get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'member')'

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834356/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-db-entrys-collection-is-part-of-a-many-to-many-re/70834712#70834712) I can see its possible to check if the collection is part of many-to-many, but is there some way to now explicitly load each item from the relationship?

entities:

```
public sealed class Company
{
    // ...
    private readonly List<Tag> _tags = new();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Tag> Tags => _tags.AsReadOnly();
    // ...
}


public sealed class Tag
{
    // ...
    private readonly List<Company> _companies = new();
    private readonly List<SomeOtherEntity> _otherEntities = new();
    // ...
}
```

configuration:

```
builder.HasMany(x => x.Tags)
    .WithMany("_companies")
    .UsingEntity(
        (joinBuilder) =>
        {
            joinBuilder.ToTable("CompaniesTags");
            joinBuilder.Property<Guid>("TagId").HasColumnName("TagId");
            joinBuilder.Property<Guid>("_companiesId").HasColumnName("CompanyId");
        });
```

The config and join table names look weird, but I can't tell if that is whats messing with me. I did try renaming the join table to `CompanyTags` but it did not seem to help.

Comment: Why not just use .Include() ?

Comment: @Neil It is a great question, and the reason is that in some instances we are performing operations which do not need to include those entities, but we still want them to be loaded in this post-processing handler. The idea is that we can turn this on/off, and the code which would call Include should not know anything about it so we create a kind of dependency by doing that

Comment: So you have a repository that exposes differing levels of includes.   Get, GetWithCompanies, GetWithTags, GetWithCompaniesAndTags etc.  Then you can specifically test those functions do what they are supposed to do, and you use the correct one in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is logged [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23717)

And the suggested workaround

> The workaround is to use a private property instead of a private field.

Appears to work:

```
public sealed class Tag
{
    // ...
    private List<Company> _companies { get; } = new();
    private List<SomeOtherEntity> _otherEntities { get; } = new();
    // ...
}
```