# Problem in populating list object in a certain way

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a class like below :

```
public class UserChangeLogs
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public string Column { get; set; }
        public string OriginalValue { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedValue { get; set; }
    }
```

This table has data like below:

```
Id      UserId      Version     Column      OriginalValue       UpdatedValue
1       100         1.0         FirstName   Jon                 John
2       100         1.0         LastName    Kid                 Kidhar
3       100         1.0         Address     abc                 Pqr
4       100         1.0         Comments                        Updated basic info
5       100         2.0         Phone       1111                222
6       100         2.0         Age         20                  21
7       100         2.0         Comments                        Update phone no and age
```

Comments for Version 1 User changes:

```
4       100         1.0         Comments                            Updated basic info
```

Comments for Version 2 User changes:

```
7       100         2.0         Comments                            Update phone no and age
```

Below is my DTO class for the output:

```
public class UserChangeLogsPOCO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public string Column { get; set; }
        public string OriginalValue { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedValue { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to get the list of User change logs for particular user 100 and have Comments only in the first record of each version. Like below :

**Output:**

```
 Id         Version     Column      OriginalValue       UpdatedValue   Comments
 5          2.0         Phone       1111                222            Update phone no and age
 6          2.0         Age         20                  21             null
 1          1.0         FirstName   Jon                 John           Updated basic info
 2          1.0         LastName    Kid                 Kidhar         null
 3          1.0         Address     abc                 Pqr            null
 .
 .
```

I just want Comments to be there in the first record of each new version.

**Code:**

```
var query = context.UserChangeLogs
                   .Where(u => u.UserId == 100)
                   .OrderByDescending(p => p.Version); //latest version data first
                    .ToList();
                    
var output = query
         .Select(a => new UserChangeLogsPOCO
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Version = a.Version,
            Column = a.Column,
            OriginalValue = a.OriginalValue,
            UpdatedValue = a.UpdatedValue,
            Comments = context.UserChangeLogs
                    .Where(u =>u.Column == "Comments" &&
                    a.UserId == u.UserId &&
                    u.Version == a.Version).
                    Select(u => u.UpdatedValue).FirstOrDefault(),
        }).ToList();
```

But the problem is I a getting "`Comments`" with each record.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a dictionary for the version comments and use it to simplify the population of the `output`'s `Comments` property.

The suggestion below is based on the assumption that for each `Version`'s collection of records associated with the target `UserId`, there is:

- exactly one record for a change in the "Comments" column
- at least one record for a change in any other column

I have marked all changes made to the original code with comments.

```
var query = context.UserChangeLogs
    .Where(u => u.UserId == 100)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Version); //latest version data first
    .ToList();

// ADDED
const string CommentsColumn = "Comments";

// ADDED
// Dictionary associating the version comment with the ID of the first record for the version
var commentForRecordWithId = query
    .GroupBy(entry => entry.Version)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.First(entry => entry.Column != CommentsColumn).Id, 
        gr => gr.First(entry => entry.Column == CommentsColumn).UpdatedValue);

var output = query
    .Where(a => a.Column != CommentsColumn) // ADDED - we don't want the Comments column change records in output
    .Select(a => new UserChangeLogsPOCO
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Version = a.Version,
        Column = a.Column,
        OriginalValue = a.OriginalValue,
        UpdatedValue = a.UpdatedValue,
        // CHANGED:
        Comments = commentForRecordWithId.ContainsKey(a.Id)
            ? commentForRecordWithId[a.Id]
            : null
    }).ToList();
```

**EDIT:** The code above also assumes that the `context.UserChangeLogs` is in chronological order, i.e. ordered by `Id`, at the time the `query` variable is assigned.

Comment: I want to get the latest audit first, so where the ordering needs to happen?

Comment: Oh, okay. According to your output example, it looked like you wanted it ordered by Id / chronologically. Could you please update your output example to display exactly which order you expect to get?

Comment: Updated expected output in the question. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Great, thank you! I've updated my answer to include the `.OrderByDescending()` from your original code that I had initially commented out - it makes sense now that you used it :)